# Could I disable `Runtime relinking` in a blazor webassembly project?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

What I mean by `Runtime relinking` is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#runtime-relinking):

---

[image]

---

It is a good feature in the most time.

However my project needs extra plugins to work. (The plugins are just `.dll` files and the project will access them with reflection.)

So will the relinking make some types or methods unusable for the plugins? How could I avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been found at https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: were you able top perhaps find a possibility to exclude certain assemblies or types in the reliniking process?

Comment: @LuckyLikey Does `<TrimmerRootAssembly>` work for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?source=recommendations&pivots=dotnet-7-0#root-assemblies